# Silverlight 5 + Internet Explorer 9 using old Content-Type from POST in a subsequent GET?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

We've been running into a super annoying problem at work.  After our Silverlight application makes it's login POST the next GET that we send fails with a NotFoundException.  This only happens when using the Silverlight 5 runtime and only happens in Internet Explorer 9.  I have tested now with Silverlight 4 as well as Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari, and IE9/SL5 is the only bad combination.

Here are the headers of our login POST:

`POST /login HTTP/1.1

Accept: application/xml

Referer: http://localhost:8080/censored.xap?timestamp=1326148328000

Accept-Language: en-CA

Content-Length: 38

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)

Host: localhost:8080

Connection: Keep-Alive

Pragma: no-cache

Cookie: JSESSIONID=DEFEAFD35E9B067A79F772C166937750`

Here are the headers of our next GET:

`GET /user/current HTTP/1.1

Accept: application/xml

Referer: http://localhost:8080/censored.xap?timestamp=1326148328000

Accept-Language: en-CA

Content-Length: 38

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)

Host: localhost:8080

Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

Pragma: no-cache

Cookie: JSESSIONID=5C57C93458E80E5975470F703B4A483C`

Notice that the Content-Type and Content-Length are identical, even though:

- You aren't allowed to use Content-Type or Content-Length on a GET
- The content length is actually different in the GET request so it's obviously the old value

Anyone else running into this?

UPDATE:
It only occurs when using BrowserHttp.

Here is some sample client code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Browser;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace NetworkTest
{
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp.Create(new Uri("http://localhost:59050/Home/Login"));
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(result =>
            {
                var rq = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;

                using (var stream = rq.EndGetRequestStream(result))
                {
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                    writer.WriteLine("username=test&password=test");
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Close();
                }

                rq.BeginGetResponse(
                    r =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            rq.EndGetResponse(r);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }, rq);
            }, request);
    }
}
}
```

Sample server code (from ASP MVC 3):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestServer.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(string test)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

You end up seeing a POST to login which is a successful request.  You get redirected back to the index page and that GET still contains the Content-Type and Content-Length from the POST and so it fails.

Full solution is available at http://www.mikecousins.com/files/NetworkTest.zip

Comment: You're using browser HTTP I guess, not Client HTTP?

Comment: Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.browser.webrequestcreator.clienthttp%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: I've tried both ClientHttp and BrowserHttp with no difference in the results.

Comment: Ok, good luck then. I've stopped experimenting with Silverlight 5 right now, as it offers nothing of what we hoped for, so I can't quickly test your case. Can you make a small repro project?

Comment: Sorry, after more investigating, it's actually only true when using the BrowserHttp stack.  I was just seeing authentication issues when using the ClientHttp stack.  I've added sample code to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

Here is the steps that I have done with your project.

1. Set specific port 59050 since you hard-coded the URL but use auto-assigned port.
2. Added Silverlight project to WebServer (Running from Casini is better than running from file. )
3. Changed _Layout.cshtml as below to add SL object

   @ViewBag.Title
       
       
       
       NetworkTest
       
       html, body {
           height: 100%;
           overflow: auto;
       }
       body {
           padding: 0;
           margin: 0;
       }
       #silverlightControlHost {
           height: 100%;
           text-align:center;
       }
       
       
       
           function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
               var appSource = "";
               if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
                   appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
               }

   ```
           var errorType = args.ErrorType;
           var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

           if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
               return;
           }

           var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + appSource + "\n";

           errMsg += "Code: " + iErrorCode + "    \n";
           errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
           errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

           if (errorType == "ParserError") {
               errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
               errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
               errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
           }
           else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {
               if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                   errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                   errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
               }
               errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
           }

           throw new Error(errMsg);
       }
   </script>
   ```

   ## My MVC Application

   @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")

   @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")

   @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")

   @RenderBody()

4.Check "Silverlight" in Web tab to enable the Silverlight debugging.
5. Put the breakpoint at rq.EndGetResponse() (line 34) in MainPage.xaml.cs.
6. Run the app (Observe: This breakpoint is going to get hit. )

Im testing with SL5 and IE9.